# Typedef function pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, c-preprocessor

I am trying to understand a code in c++ header.

```
#define GET_VAL(fn) void fn(int val)
typedef GET_VAL ((*get_val));
struct myStruct
{ 
    get_val getValue;
};
```

In the source file, the function getValue is called.

```
getValue(2);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is a horrible way to declare a function pointer. I don't see a reason to use the macro like that other than obfuscation.

Comment: It is a piece of code in a big project. I just gave a simplified version. Maybe they have their own consideration. Anyway you are right, it did obfuscate me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `GET_VAL` macro substitutes the tokens you pass to it. This:

```
typedef GET_VAL ((*get_val));
```

Expands to:

```
typedef void (*get_val) (int val);
```

That is a pointer to a function which takes an `int` and returns nothing. A function pointer of this type is declared in `myStruct` (which is presumably defined at some point) and called like a regular function.

Comment: Thanks Tartan. Solved my confusion.